# Matching Values with the keys

Tags: javascript

Here is my custom Object made for comparsion.. from the response i get the `value` and now i have to match the value with the `keys` in this object and return the `key`.

Comment: Can you be clearer? You want to match the value with the key and return the key? Are you trying to check if the value is present in the object?

Comment: @pradeek: Yes i want to compare

Comment: Then check if heartRateRegular[key] is undefined or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could work for you:

```
for(key in heartRateRegular)
   if (key == value)
       return key;
```

The `for..in` clause iterates through all of the keys of the object. That's if you want to check the value you get against the `Keys` of your object. If you want to check the value against the `Values` of your object, do the following:

```
for(key in heartRateRegular)
   if (heartRateRegular[key] == value)
       return key;
```

Comment: But i am getting the response as Irregularly Irregular which is value, how would i check whether its present or not

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
function getValueFromKey(key) {
    for (key in heartRateRegular) {
        if (heartRateRegular[key] == response) return key;
    }
}

var heartRateRegular = {
    I: 'Irregular',
    Ii: 'Irregularly Irregular',
    Ir: 'Irregularly Regular',
    R: 'Regular',
    Ri: 'Regularly Irregular'
}

response = 'Irregularly Irregular';
alert(getValueFromKey(response));
//alerts 'Ii'
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/WydQh/

Comment: Its easier and better to check if heartRateRegular[key] is undefined or not